# For loops in Discord.py, adding roles to every member is not functioning as predicted

Tags: python, for-loop, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am creating a discord bot using discord.py that will add a specific role to every single member on the server.

```
guild_members = guild.members
Role = await guild.create_role(name="Role", permissions = Permissions(permissions=66560))
for m in guild_members:
    await m.add_role(Role)
```

Where `guild` is the guild object we are focusing on.
This does not appear to function as I intend to, where it will create a specific role and add it to every single person on the server. In fact, adding a print statement inside the for loop does not yield any result either in the command line. What is the cause of this problem, and how may I fix it?

Comment: Did you enable `intents.members`?

Comment: Yes, I enabled it, fetch_guild, members, etc all function in other commands.

Comment: Does the bot create the role?

Comment: Yes, it does add the role.